# Using R to convert rows of text in a CSV file into separate 'txt' files

Tags: r, text

I'm using R to analyse separate rows of text and would like to convert each row of text into its own separate txt file. The current CSV file has 3 columns:
column 1: ID number,
column 2: text to be exported into its own unique txt file
column 3: The name that I would like each row's respective 'txt' file to be named.

Could anyone help with what package/coding would be best to do this?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like the following.

```
dat <- read.csv("yourfile.csv")
apply(dat, 1, function(x) write.table(data.frame(x[2]), file = x[3], row.names = FALSE))
```

Answer (score 0):

First you need to import your data. You can do that in a number of ways. Once you have a data.frame, you can split it using `split`. Try something like `split(x, f = 1:nrow(x))`. You can write each list element using `sapply(splitx, FUN = function(x) write.table(x, ...))`.